# How can I format JSON string after conversion from pyspark dataframe?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have converted data frame to JSON by using `toJSON` in `pyspark` that gives me each row as JSON  string. but I want to reformat a bit

My code is given below:

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"

def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=spark.sql(sqlval)
    df.show()
    return df

result=queryBuilder(sqlstring)
resultlist=result.toJSON().collect()
print(resultlist)
print("Type of",type(resultlist))
```

After this, the output is:

```
[
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"10230104","City":"Edmonton","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2312","DID":"79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8","MID":"79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8"}',
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Renew","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"1040HAMI","City":"Vancouver","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"784","DID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e","MID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e"}', 
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Renew","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"1040HAMI","City":"Vancouver","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2223","DID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e","MID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e"}', 
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Conditional","property":"106PORTW","City":"Toronto","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2212","DID":"69c3af0527014fd99d1ccf156c0bce93","MID":"69c3af0527014fd99d1ccf156c0bce93"}', 
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"106PORTW","City":"Toronto","DealType":"0","Area":"","DID":"04aedb01da5d44fead7e1315115c2530","MID":"04aedb01da5d44fead7e1315115c2530"}'
]
```

But I want to format this JSON Array like for example: the following two rows:

```
[
    {
        "LeaseType": "Offer to Lease",
        "Status": "Fully Executed",
        "property": "10230104",
        "City": "Edmonton",
        "DealType": "Renewal",
        "Area": "2312",
        "DID": "79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8",
        "MID": "79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8"
    },
    {
        "LeaseType": "Offer to Renew",
        "Status": "Fully Executed",
        "property": "1040HAMI",
        "City": "Vancouver",
        "DealType": "Renewal",
        "Area": "784",
        "DID": "ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e",
        "MID": "ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e"
    }
]
```

I want to omit the **'** here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
import json

resultlist = [
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"10230104","City":"Edmonton","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2312","DID":"79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8","MID":"79cc3959ffc8403f943ff0e7e93584f8"}',
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Renew","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"1040HAMI","City":"Vancouver","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"784","DID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e","MID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e"}',
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Renew","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"1040HAMI","City":"Vancouver","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2223","DID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e","MID":"ecf922d0583247c0a4cb591bd4b3843e"}',
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Conditional","property":"106PORTW","City":"Toronto","DealType":"Renewal","Area":"2212","DID":"69c3af0527014fd99d1ccf156c0bce93","MID":"69c3af0527014fd99d1ccf156c0bce93"}',
    '{"LeaseType":"Offer to Lease","Status":"Fully Executed","property":"106PORTW","City":"Toronto","DealType":"0","Area":"","DID":"04aedb01da5d44fead7e1315115c2530","MID":"04aedb01da5d44fead7e1315115c2530"}'
]

data_to_dump = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
json_data= json.dumps(data_to_dump)
print json_data
```

Comment: Don't use re module. Properly `json.loads` the json strings

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of JSON strings, so if you want to get that entire list as a JSON block, you can load the JSON back to python dictionaries, then serialize the whole list

```
import json

resultlist_json = [json.loads(x) for x in resultlist] 
print(json.dumps(resultlist_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```